# How convert 2 string columns (date and time) to one timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have table with two columns (both string):

```
| Dates    | Times          |

| -------- | -------------- |

|20210401  | 121012         |

|20210401  | 121024         |
```

And I would like to combine these columns into one in timestamp format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I tried this, but it is wrong:

```
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATES, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(6), TIMES, 108))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server allows you to add `datetime` values, so that is a convenient data type for this purpose.

It is easy to convert the date to a `datetime` -- it is in a standard format.

The time column is tricker, but you can add in `':'` for the conversion:

```
select v.*,
       convert(datetime, v.date) + convert(datetime, stuff(stuff(time, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
from (values ('20210401',  '121012')) v(date, time);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
convert(datetime, DATES + ' ' + substring(TIMES, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(TIMES, 3, 2) + ':' + substring(TIMES, 5, 2) , 121)
```